# initialize component working in if condition?

Tags: c#, winforms, idisposable

I am trying to create new solution which consist of 2 projects. Solution Startup Project is "Main Component" project and the other project is "Login Function" project.

Basicly MainForm in "Main Component" calling LoginForm in "Login Function" When the Solution start. I wrote a condition in MainForm Constructor for calling LoginForm and working perfectly but I receive an error like as follow in Program.cs when escape from LoginForm. Because initializeComponent() part working when if condition is true. I don't know if another way to do that.

I know Solution is working but How can I fix this Dispose problem?

Program.cs;

```
namespace Main_Component
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            using (var mainForm = new MainForm())
            {
                Application.Run(mainForm);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'MainForm'.

```
public MainForm()
    {
        try
        {
            var _lForm=new LoginForm();
            _lForm.ShowDialog();
            if (LoginForm._loginSuccess)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            else
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of launching `MainForm` why not launch `LoginForm` from `Main()` and have that launch `MainForm()` on a sucessful login.

Comment: Thats mean I will change to startup proect as Login Function and ofcourse I should hide the loginform and show mainform If I do like you said but I do not want to hide startup project.

Comment: @Okan No, it doesn't.  Have `Main` launch the login form as it's own main form, with its own application loop.  When it ends, launch a new main form with a new application loop.

Comment: @Servy I see What you mean perfectly. And I tried to use run login form in mainform constructor but Mainform initializeComponent running at start as you know. I am trying to prevent show mainform before loginform. I tried to do that but I didn't figured out how

Comment: @Okan So don't create the login form in the constructor of the main form, create and show it in the main method *before the main form is even constructed*.

Comment: @Scott you were right. I had understood correctly but  When I read again your message, I changed location of code MainForm() to Main() and working perfectly. Thank you so much

Comment: @Servy yeah I reliaze my mistake and I changed as both of you said. And thank you too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue that you are not properly disposing IDisposable component.
You need to have a better structure of your as so you do not new your components by hands.
But you can fix exsting conde with following `using` usage:

```
public MainForm()
    {
        try
        {
            using(var _lForm=new LoginForm())
            {
                _lForm.ShowDialog();
                if (LoginForm._loginSuccess)
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah @klashar, you absolutely right about 'using' usage but Result is same. Still receiving 'Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'MainForm''